# select values which contains specific characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database table which contains questions in hindi and english language in same column but are separated by keyword [en] english language [en:] and [hi] hindi language [hi:] and some of them are not separated by language tags

I want to select only that questions which have  [en] [en:] and  [hi][hi:] tags in mysql

Comment: Are the tags part of the question? or a separate field?

Comment: Post a sample question with tag included in it

Comment: tegs are part of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select *
From mytable
Where mycolumn like '%[en]%[en:]%'
    and mycolumn like '%[hi]%[hi:]%'
```

Note that this query will not be very performant but that's what you get for not normalizing your database.

You could use a regex match to ensure not finding 'tags' that contain other tags like [en]foo[hi]bar[en:] but that would make performance even worse.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from table_name
 where question like '%[en]%' or 
       question like '%[en:]%' or 
       question like '%[hi]%' or 
       question like '%[hi:]%'
```

If the start tag is of format `'[en]'` and end tag is of format `'[en:]'`, then

```
Select * from table_name
 where question like '%[en]%[en:]' or 
       question like '%[hi]%[hi:]'
```

Comment: `If the start tag is of format '[en]' and end tag is of format '[en:]', then` > The question states: *I want to select only that questions which have [en] [en:] **and** [hi][hi:] tags in mysql*

Comment: I added `[en]` as one example. I know that there exists other formats like `[hi]`. See my answer as well

Comment: Point is that your query in your answer matches questions that have *either* `[en]foo[en:]` **or** `[hi]bar[hi:]`. Rahul wants to match questions that have *both*. For example `[en]foo[en:] [xx]whoop![xx:] [hi]bar[hi:]` should match but not `[en]foo[en:] [xx]whoop![xx:]` (at least: that's how I understand the question)

Comment: I am not sure if the same row contains both versions of questions in the same column. OP though claims *in the same column*, I fear *it is not same row*.

Comment: Ah that would make (a bit :P ) more sense. Also: did you 'miss' the wildcard(s) at the end of your second queries on purpose? Shouldn't `like '%[en]%[en:]' or ...` be `like '%[en]%[en:]%' or ...`? If OP could clarify the data in the table a `like '[en]%[en:]' or...` might even suffice which might actually even use indexes...

Answer (score 0):

Add another column eq enum type EN => [Y,N] HI [Y,N], you can use query like in other questions to update database. So its more optimal that use like search every time

Comment: Nonsense; INNODB supports LIKE queries just as well as MyISAM.

Comment: Ye true, i made a mistake i mean full text search

Comment: INNODB supports full text search just as well (just like MyISAM). Also adding another column like you suggest is NOT the way to go. OP needs to add a column 'language_id' and add another table with languages and use FK's like they're intended to.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work

```
Select * from table_name
       where question like '%en%'
```